# Nodejs events captured in any cluster process sent from cluster creating file

Tags: node.js, events, node-cluster

I am stuck here due to a simple event related issue. Here is the issue:

- I have created a cluster using cluster.js and forked server.js from
  cluster.js.
- I have put a timer from cluster.js and after every 1 min    I am
  triggering an event 'testTimer'. I have used a event file to do
  it.
- I am trying to capture this event 'testTimer' from the child
  process using the same file I have imported into server.js and doing 
  a .on('testTimer', callback)

However, the events are not captured in any of the processes. I have tried making the event global and assign the event globally to a symbol but was unable to get it work/capture event as well.

Here is the codes:

### cluster.js (child process creator)

```
...require > events.js...
... create cluster logic...
setInterval(function () {
 evt.emit('testTimer', {tester: 'test'});
 evt.tester();
}, 1000);
```

### server.js (child process)

```
...require > events.js...
evt.on('testTimer', function (data) {

    console.log('Starting Sync ', data);
});
```

### events.js (common file for events)

```
var util         = require("util");
var EventEmitter = require("events").EventEmitter;

function test () {
    EventEmitter.call(this);
}
test.prototype.tester = function (){
    this.emit('testTimer', {missed: 'this'})
}
util.inherits(test, EventEmitter);
module.exports = test;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EventEmitter instances can't reach beyond the bounds of a process. If you want to communicate between parent and children, use [`worker.send()`](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_worker_send_message_sendhandle_callback):

```
// cluster.js
setInterval(function () {
  for (const id in cluster.workers) {
    cluster.workers[id].send({ type : 'testTimer', data : { tester : 'test' }});
  }
}, 1000);

// server.js
process.on('message', function(message) {
  if (message.type === 'testTimer') { 
    console.log('Starting Sync ', message.data);
  }
})
```

Comment: Hmm.... Did I look so stupid. Ouch... Let me try this. I ignored this fact completely/ But will globals also not be captured? I tried this as well ... `const EVT_KEY = Symbol.for('commonseventservice'); global[EVT_KEY] = new EventsClass();`

Comment: Globals, or even regular variables, will work, but they should be considered read-only: if you change such a variable in the master process, those changes won't be transferred to the children. A newly forked process will initially share its memory with its parent, until you make changes.

Comment: Ok does that mean that globals for each process master or child will be a different object respectively?

Comment: Yes and no. They will refer to the same piece of memory, so in that respect they are the same object. But once you make any change to the object (from either the parent or the child), that piece of memory is copied "into" the process that changes it and the changes will be local to the process that is making the changes (this is called [_copy-on-write_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write)).

Comment: Hmm... this is exactly the behavior I was seeing in the global assignation. Thanks a ton. I must mention I did try assigning the global object with a singleton without a object freeze since I was unable to make changes/add eventlisteners and it had not worked as well. It showed one set of listeners in child and one set of listeners in cluster.js Now I see the reason.

Comment: Can I move away from copy-on-write?

Comment: Not from Node (or at least, not easily). You'd need threads, which come with their own challenges (like having to synchronize changes).

Comment: Any good read or resource for the same? Its okay even if you just point me to them. Though I will go with workers/master communication for the moment, I would definitely want to explore how it can be done.

Comment: I have no idea if there are working threading implementations for Node, tbh.

Comment: No. I was looking at `having to synchronize changes`. I had heard it is possible but never looked at a resource mentioning the same. I am not sure if multi-threading might be possible without an extension that creates tailing threads/pool from single threaded nodejs. May be I am wrong.

Comment: I means "synchronizing changes" in the context of multithreading. What you're looking for (I think) is to coordinate between processes, for which the easiest solution would be the IPC offered by `worker.send()`.

Comment: Ok got your point. I actually thought 'synchronizing changes' literally